# Adding rows dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form containing a select field id="projects" which upon being changed shows a hidden select field 'task' dynamically populating the tasks for the selected project by querying the dB. User can then enter hours which are updated on proj_id,task_id combination from the selects. Following code shows the 'task' select when 'Projects' is changed.

```
$('.tasks').hide();
$('#projects').change(function(){
    $('.tasks').show();
    $('.tasks').append("<option>1</option><option>New Task</option>");
});
```

I then added the functionality of clicking a button that replicates the form, each row contains 1.select 'project' 2. hidden select 'task' shown on project select 3. hidden textbox activated when New Task option is selected 4. hour input boxes for the whole week.

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    $('#row').clone().appendTo('#dynform');
});
```

The functionality needed is that each user be able to add rows and choose different project-task combinations to log hours against them.

The problem here is that when I change the first rows projects all the added rows get affected too, I am not able to seperate them out. I am new to dynamically changing things in a web-page. Please help me out.

Working Fiddle of the whole thing - http://jsfiddle.net/PuWMK/1/

Comment: Not clear what your problem is ?

Comment: Basically every rows elements need to be treated separately, like they have their own Id, I don't know how to achieve that. If you add a couple of rows in the fiddle and choose a project, you'll see what I'm saying

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$('.tasks').hide();
$('#dynform').on('change' , '#projects', function(){
    $(this).next('.tasks').show()
    .append("<option>1</option><option>New Task</option>")
});

$('#add').click(function () {
    $('#row').clone().appendTo('#dynform');
});

$('.tasks').change(function(){
    $('#new').css('visibility','visible');
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/PuWMK/2/)

Comment: How can I access these by $_POST on submit. Do I need to name them as project[] and task[], If so what do I do for hours which is already an hours[], do I make it hours[][]?

Comment: There is no name for your inputs, you have to give a name, in this case you can use a name like `inputOne[]` for every first `textbox` in a row so, you can access them in the server from the post as `$inputOneArray = $_POST['inputOne']` and can do a `foreach` loop.